# Mismatch between print preview and real print output

Tags: visual-c++, printing, mfc, print-preview

I want to print a bitmap. To avoid printing small bitmap I set `CScrollView` mode as `MM_LOMETRIC` with sizes 3830 x 1995. I have created the bitmap and made the bitblt to the screen. There were everythig just like I want on the screen and on the print preview but when I printed the document I've got [very bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3Ig2.jpg).

The same picture on [print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xF7JJ.jpg).

It seems to me that printer does not see a bitmap the same way as print preview does.

Pay attantion that the first ractangle puts directly on the DC and memDC puts into it.

Are there any ideas how to fix this mismatch between print previw and the real printing?

[Project files](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/6M28/HGF7dzmLu)

```
void OnDraw()
{
    CPen pen;
    pen.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 1, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    CPen* OldPen = pDC->SelectObject(&pen);

    CRect rcView;
    GetClientRect(rcView);
    int iClientWidth = rcView.right;
    int iClientHeight = rcView.bottom;
    int iMemWidth = 1900;
    int iMemHeight = 950;
    CDC memDC;
    CBitmap memBitmap;
    memDC.CreateCompatibleDC(pDC);
    memBitmap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(pDC, iMemWidth, iMemHeight);
    memDC.SelectObject(&memBitmap);
    memDC.SetMapMode(MM_LOMETRIC);
    CPen pen1;
    pen1.CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    memDC.SelectObject(&pen1);
    CBrush brBK;
    brBK.CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 255));
    memDC.SelectObject(&brBK);
    RECT rc;
    rc.left = 0;
    rc.top = 0;
    rc.right = iMemWidth;
    rc.bottom = iMemHeight;
    memDC.FillRect(&rc, &brBK);
    memDC.Rectangle(rc.left, rc.top, rc.right, -rc.bottom);
    memDC.MoveTo(0, 0);
    memDC.LineTo(1900, -950);

    memDC.MoveTo(0, -950);
    memDC.LineTo(200, -750);

    CFont font;
    font.CreateFont(
        50,                        // nHeight
        0,                         // nWidth
        0,                         // nEscapement
        0,                         // nOrientation
        FW_NORMAL,                 // nWeight
        FALSE,                     // bItalic
        FALSE,                     // bUnderline
        0,                         // cStrikeOut
        ANSI_CHARSET,              // nCharSet
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,       // nClipPrecision
        DEFAULT_QUALITY,           // nQuality
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
        _T("Arial"));
    memDC.SelectObject(&font);
    memDC.TextOut(100, -100, _T("Hello"));


    pDC->BitBlt(10, -10, iMemWidth, -iMemHeight, &memDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    font.DeleteObject();
    brBK.DeleteObject();
    memDC.DeleteDC();
    memBitmap.DeleteObject();
    pen.DeleteObject();
    pen1.DeleteObject();
}

void OnInitialUpdate()
{
    CScrollView::OnInitialUpdate();

    CSize sizeTotal;
    sizeTotal.cx = 3830;
    sizeTotal.cy = 1995;
    SetScrollSizes(MM_LOMETRIC, sizeTotal);
}
```

Comment: Printer's left margin is probably .25 inch or more. This value is obtained from `GetDeviceCaps(hdc, PHYSICALOFFSETX)`. It's not possible to print outside the printable area.

Comment: Thak you for the answer but there is a problem with the bitmap that is inscribed in the ractangle.
If you look at the print preview - you will see this bitmap well. But if you print the real page you will see that ractangle is printed perfectly but the bitmap (inscribed into ractangle) was cut from the right side and the bottom.